# JSP not accessing static content for more then one page

Tags: java, css, spring, jsp

I have `css,js,... other static` pages in `webapp/` and i have created a seperated file for them as `theme.jsp` with content as :

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- bootstrap theme -->
<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--external css-->
<!-- font icon -->
<link href="css/elegant-icons-style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Custom styles -->
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Now the problem is I am not able to access this content in more then one jsp page

I am using spring and below is my servlet configuration

```
@Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        LOG.debug("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Default Servlet Configuration Enabled");
        configurer.enable();
    }
@Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        LOG.info("++++++++++++++ Configuring View resolver");
        InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        internalResourceViewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        internalResourceViewResolver.setCache(false);
        LOG.info("++++++++++++++ View resolver Configuration: Done");
        return internalResourceViewResolver;
    }

@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/");
    }
```

Can you please guide me how to solve this, So I can access static contents in all `jsp's`

Edit: Consider I have a single `css` file inside `css/style.css`  and I am going to use it in entire project. therefore I made a `jsp` named `theme.jsp` and it contains only links to my css resources. Not the problem I am facing is that I am able to access this `css/style.css` in one jsp but in other I am not able to call. Even If I copy `jsp` file I am getting no result

Comment: Your explanation is bit unclear. Could you please explain what you want to do with theme.jsp? what is ur requirement?

Comment: You can include theme.jsp in other JSPs

Comment: @user7294900 yes sir it is working fine in my one page but pages it is not working

Comment: @user7036414 so you are able to add theme.jsp and its purpose is to include all css files. 
(**it is working fine in my one page but pages it is not working**) -> what is not working? please make it clear.

Comment: @RahulRaj It is only working in one `jsp`

Comment: **You're trying to import theme.jsp in another jsp pages and its not working** -> is that what you mean?

Comment: Actually It is working in one jsp but not in others

Comment: what's the error? if you don't find debug or add catch exception

Comment: thanks it turned out to be `css` error and after changing the css file it is resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

Create your custom jsp tag and define all common files in that tag :

```
<%@tag description="Overall Page template" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@attribute name="header" fragment="true" %>
<%@attribute name="footer" fragment="true" %>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="pageheader">
      <jsp:invoke fragment="header"/>
    </div>
    <div id="body">
      <jsp:doBody/>
    </div>
    <div id="pagefooter">
      <jsp:invoke fragment="footer"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

define this tag in **WEB-INF/tags/customtag.tag**
To use this :

> import <%@taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %> in your jsp page